# Не могу создать больше одного перехода от анимации

Tags: unity3d

В Unity при создании 2d игры столкнулся с проблемой. Оказалось,что от одной анимации невозможно создать более одного перехода (transition). В окне Animator настраиваю переходы между анимациями. У меня 3 анимации- бездействие, бег и прыжок. Переход от Бездействия к Бегу настроил. Решил так же сделать переход от Бездействия к Прыжку. Но при нажатии правой кнопки мыши по анимации Бездействия просто не появляется опция "создать переход" ("Make Transition"). Т.е. первый переход создаётся без проблем, но после этого программа не даёт создать ещё один переход!.
Для эксперимента попробовал создать два перехода от Бега к Бездействию и к Прыжку. Тоже не получилось. Первый переход создаётся, а второй не получается.
Посмотрел несколько видео-уроков, прочёл несколько статей. У всех авторов нет такой проблемы. Они легко добавляют дополнительные переходы. Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно? Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Какая у вас версия Unity? Чаще всего с такой проблемой сталкиваются пользователи с не стабильными версиями.

Comment: @ Pantheon, версия Unity 2020.3.32f1 (64-bit)

Comment: Попробуй другие версии, лично я пользуюсь 2020.3.25f1, там нет такой проблемы. Если проблема не в версии то я не знаю, поищу ещё инфы.

Comment: @ Pantheon, поставил новую версию. Всё заработало нормально. Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Не за что! Я оформил это как ответ, отметь верным что бы другие тоже узнали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй другие версии, лично я пользуюсь 2020.3.25f1, там нет такой проблемы.